# how to unmarshall an empty tag using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following xml . I want to un-marshall using jaxb.

```
<books>
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <biography/>
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <fiction/>
</book>
```

I want to know how to un-marshall biography and fiction tags. also keeping in view of future requirement, other books can be added with different categories like ,  etc.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not do a google search? I have already found a tutorial link. http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ If you have faced any particular problem, tell us in detail.

Comment: i have already seen a tutorial. the problem which i am facing is with unmarshalling of empty tag that is <biography/> . also, as mentioned in the exmaple, value for empty tag may change as biography, fiction etc. i did not find solution for unmarshalling the empty tag. i tried google search for this but could not find relevant part. if anybody can help that would be great

Comment: then what you expect for unmarshalling an empty tag and what are you getting? For example you are getting an exception but you want to set null as property. Is this your scenario?